# Create PDF with NodeJS, Jade and PhantomJS

Tags: css, node.js, pdf, phantomjs, pug

I want to create a PDF from a template in Jade using PhantomJS, I can create the PDF document, but the CSS is not applying, I create two routes the first one render the template to the web browser and the second one generate de PDF with the exact same jade template, in the browser all is right, but the PDF don't apply CSS.

My app.js is:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/api/cotizacion/generar', routes.cotizacion.generar);
app.get('/api/cotizacion/generar', routes.cotizacion.testGenerar);

app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.send(404);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.info('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The controller file is cotizacion.js:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

exports.generar = function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.body.cotizacion){
        return next(new Error('No se enviaron datos de cotización'));
    }

    var cotizacion = req.body.cotizacion;

    req.app.render('test', {cotizacion: cotizacion}, function(err, html){
        generarPDF(cotizacion, html, function(){
            res.send("1");
        });
    });
};

exports.testGenerar = function(req, res, next){
    res.render('test', {});
};

generarPDF = function(cotizacion, html, callback){
    phantom.create(function(ph){
        ph.createPage(function(page){
            page.set('paperSize', { format: 'Letter' });
            page.set('content', html);
            page.render(__dirname + '/test.pdf', function(err){
                ph.exit();
                callback();
            }); 
        });
    });
}
```

And finally my test.jade is:

```
doctype html

html
    head
        title Cotización PDF
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/pdf.css')

    body
        h1 Test
```

The following works, but is a little annoying

```
doctype html

html
    head
        title Cotización PDF
        | <style type="text/css">
        |   body{ color: green; }
        | </style>

    body
        h1 Test
```

The project structure is:

```
/
   app.js
   public/
      css/
         pdf.css
   routes/
      index.js
      cotizador.js
   views/
      test.jade
```

Comment: Have you managed this issue ? We've been strugling with the same problem for a while... and can't figure out what is wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is our solution for similar problem. Below JADE template, notice hrefs with a reference to JSON object properties:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", media="all", href=report.statics.bootstrap)
    link(rel='stylesheet', type="text/css", media="all", href=report.statics.custom)
  body
```

Here is a code snippet, used for providing to the template CSS paths:

```
var createStatics = function (req) {
  var hostName = url.format({protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.get('host')
  });
  return {
    bootstrap: hostName + '/assets/reports/bootstrap-report.css',
    custom: hostName + '/assets/reports/custom.css',
  }
}
```

Next here is a JADE template compilation:

```
var fn = jade.compile(template);
```

Transportation object, used for passing required by JADE template utility objects:

```
  var report = {
    statics: statics,
    title: 'Simple report title'
  };
```

Rendering HTML report and retrieved as a stream...

```
  var output = fn({
    report: report
  });
```